# connect Spyder IDE to remote Cloudera environment

Tags: pyspark, ide, anaconda, cloudera, spyder

I have installed Anaconda3 (64 bit) in my local windows machine, where Spyder IDE is installed. I want to connect the Spyder IDE to the Cloudera Hadoop cluster, so that I can write my PYSPARK scripts in Spyder IDE for that remote Cloudera Hadoop cluster. What are the steps I have to follow to connect to the remote cluster & to execute pyspark code from my local windows machine.